# How to redirect site from www to non-www

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have codeigniter project and I have `.htaccess` with the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I want to keep this as I do not want `index.php` in the address bar.

I have a domain `example.com`. Now when I try `https://www.example.com` then it must redirect to `https://example.com`.

How can I do that with the `.htaccess` file above?

Comment: Nope. Not working.  I am getting 404 error.For this url: example.com/abc

Comment: Sorry its unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by `Now I want to keep this index.php as I do not want index.php in addressbar` ?

Comment: @AmitVerma I think they mean that they want to keep that rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Yes @Vickel you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following directives *before* your existing rule to redirect everything from www to non-www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the hostname, less the `www.` prefix, from the preceding *CondPattern* ie. the value of `(.+?)`.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path that was requested.

This also removes an optional trailing dot on the hostname, should a FQDN be requested, eg. `www.example.com.`. This requires the preceding capturing group to be non-greedy, ie. `(.+?)`, as opposed to simply `(.+)` (which would capture the trailing dot).

Comment: Thanks it works. And also thank you for giving me proper understanding of this rule. I learnt it with this answer. Once again thank you :)