# 307 redirect in .htaccess is this correct?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect, http-status-code-307

I need to have many pages redirect temporarily to an old site via `.htaccess` as I migrate it.

Do I just need to add this line for each 307 redirect to `.htaccess`?

```
Redirect 307 /page_one https://www.oldsite.com/page_one
```

My entire `.htaccess` would look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(wp-content/uploads/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Redirect 307 /page_one https://www.oldsite.com/page_one
Redirect 307 /page_two https://www.oldsite.com/page_two
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Presumably you are only doing this for a subset of pages, not all pages?

Comment: @MrWhite yes the client wants to restructure the site and I'm training them on wordpress in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 307 /page_one https://www.oldsite.com/page_one
> Redirect 307 /page_two https://www.oldsite.com/page_two
> ```

Yes, you can do exactly this if you are only wanting to redirect specific pages.

However, since this appears to be a WordPress site, you should place these directives outside of the `# BEGIN WordPress` .. `# END WordPress` block, since WP itself will try to maintain this block of directives and might overwrite your directives.

These mod_alias directives can be placed before or after the WP code block - it does not matter. mod_alias is processed after mod_rewrite anyway, so the order of the directives in the config file really does not matter.

Note, however, that the `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target. So, in your example, `/page_one/foo` would also be redirected to `https://www.oldsite.com/page_one/foo`.

If the target URL-path is always the same as the source URL-path then you can use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive with a backreference instead to save repetition. This matches using a regex, rather than simple prefix-matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 307 ^/page_three$ https://www.oldsite.com$0
```

This only matches `/page_three` exactly and redirects to `https://www.oldsite.com/page_three`. Where the `$0` backreference is the entire URL-path that is matched by the preceding regex (2nd argument), ie. `/page_three` in this example.

If you are only redirecting GET requests then a 302 (temporary) would suffice, so you could omit the status codes, since 302 is the default:

```
RedirectMatch ^/page_four$ https://www.oldsite.com$0
```

Comment: does RedirectMatch also work for https://www. vs not https:// without www.

Comment: @pointydrip No, because the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive matches against the URL-path only. To match the hostname (ie. www vs non-www) you need to use a mod_rewrite _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable. For example, to redirect from www to non-www see the my answer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65053686/369434

Comment: Do the 'RewriteRule' need to be different for 'RedirectMatch' to work?

Comment: @pointydrip I'm not sure what you mean? `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` belong to different Apache modules and use a different syntax.